# where do I put the comma if any? After Please or would or allow?

Tags: punctuation

Please if you would allow three (3) business days for a reply back I will be forwarding this information over to my manager to review?

Comment: "would allow three days" is all part of the same clause, so you should not use a comma there. However, you can use a comma after please, and should also use a comma after back. As it was mentioned in an answer, the sentence is not grammatically correct. "If you would please allow three business days for a reply, I would be forwarding this information over to my manager for review." is better.

Comment: Better yet might be to break it up into two sentences: "Would you allow three business days for a reply? If so, I will forward this information over to my manager for review."

Answer (score 1):

I added two commas:

> Please, if you would allow three (3) business days for a reply back, I will be forwarding this information over to my manager to review?

You can put commas before and after a phrase. The part of your sentence that says, "if you would allow three (3) business days for a reply back" is a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are many structural issues with this sentence/question, so where the comma goes is not really relevant. I would structure the sentence as follows:

"I will forward this information to my manager for his (her?) review, and will reply to you in three business days."

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't take into account that the other party may or may not allow those extra days, or that the OP is asking for those extra days.